# Why does the key received by `__getitem__` become `0`?

Tags: python

I was implementing a `__getitem__` method for a class and found that `obj[key]` worked as expected, but `key in obj` always transformed `key` into `0`:

```py
class Mapper:
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    print(f'Retrieving {key!r}')
    if key == 'a':
      return 1
    else:
      raise KeyError('This only contains a')
```

```
>>> mapper['a']
Retrieving 'a'
1
```

```
>>> 'a' in mapper
Retrieving 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'This only contains a'
```

I didn't find a `__hasitem__` method, so I thought the `in` check worked by just calling `__getitem__` and checking if it throws a `KeyError`. I couldn't figure out how the key gets transformed into an integer, of all things!

I couldn't find an answer here, so I started writing this question. I figured out the answer before I posted, but in the interest of saving other people some time, I'll post my question and solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, so I totally forgot the method I was looking for is called [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), not `__hasitem__`!

What's more, the fallback isn't the same as other, similar dunder methods in Python! Usually I'd expect that if `__contains__` is missing, it would just use `__getitem__`. Instead, the `in` syntax uses a [special series of fallbacks](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

1. If `__contains__` exists, use that.
2. Else, if [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) exists, use it to iterate over the items in the object and check if any of them match the key.
3. Else, if `__getitem__` exists, use it to iterate over the items in the object as if it were a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) (e.g. a list): give `__getitem__` every integer, starting at `0`, and either stop when it throws an `IndexError` or it returns something matching the key.

In my case, I was raising a `KeyError` when `__getitem__` received `0`, which got passed up to the caller.